# Get all data contain inscrease number Regexp_like - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I have a table like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUr3D.png)

Now, I have get all rows formatnbr = 101 using regexp_like(nbr, expression). I'm using regexp_like (nbr, '^\d((\d)1(\1)2(\1)3)') but I have to write 7 expression with 'OR' in where clause:

```
select * from tbl where regexp(nbr, '^\d((\d)1(\1)2(\1)3)') or regexp(nbr, '^\d((\d)2(\1)3(\1)4)') or ...
```

How do I using 1 format likely in description column: regexp_like(nbr, '^\dxyx(y+1)x(y+2)') to select? Help me please!

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3wkd.png)

```
create table tbl
(
  formatnbr     NUMBER not null,
  nbr           VARCHAR2(7),
  description   VARCHAR2(50)
);

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (100, '8123456',    'Dx(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)');

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (101,   '8111213',  'Dxyx(y+1)x(y+2)');

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (100, '7456789',    'Dx(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)');

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (101, '9232425',    'Dxyx(y+1)x(y+2)');

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (101, '5565758',    'Dxyx(y+1)x(y+2)');

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (100, '0456789',    'Dx(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)');

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) values (101, '1454647',    'Dxyx(y+1)x(y+2)');
 
commit;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please, describe the rule to extract the information yo need. A BB d post sample data in text format

Comment: Thanks, I added sample data with sql.

Answer (score 0):

For:

- `Dx(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)` you can list the possible values as:

  ```
  012345|123456|234567|345678|456789
  ```
- `Dxyx(y+1)x(y+2)` you can list the possible `y` values and use backreferences to match the `x` values as

  ```
  (\d)(0(\1)1(\1)2|1(\1)2(\1)3|2(\1)3(\1)4|3(\1)4(\1)5|4(\1)5(\1)6|5(\1)6(\1)7|6(\1)7(\1)8|7(\1)8(\1)9)
  ```

So your inserts would be:

```sql
create table tbl
(
  formatnbr     NUMBER not null,
  nbr           VARCHAR2(7),
  description   VARCHAR2(110)
);

insert into tbl(formatnbr, nbr, description) 
SELECT 100, '8123456', '012345|123456|234567|345678|456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, '8111213', '(\d)(0(\1)1(\1)2|1(\1)2(\1)3|2(\1)3(\1)4|3(\1)4(\1)5|4(\1)5(\1)6|5(\1)6(\1)7|6(\1)7(\1)8|7(\1)8(\1)9)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, '7456789', '012345|123456|234567|345678|456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, '9232425', '(\d)(0(\1)1(\1)2|1(\1)2(\1)3|2(\1)3(\1)4|3(\1)4(\1)5|4(\1)5(\1)6|5(\1)6(\1)7|6(\1)7(\1)8|7(\1)8(\1)9)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, '5565758', '(\d)(0(\1)1(\1)2|1(\1)2(\1)3|2(\1)3(\1)4|3(\1)4(\1)5|4(\1)5(\1)6|5(\1)6(\1)7|6(\1)7(\1)8|7(\1)8(\1)9)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, '0456789', '012345|123456|234567|345678|456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, '1454647', '(\d)(0(\1)1(\1)2|1(\1)2(\1)3|2(\1)3(\1)4|3(\1)4(\1)5|4(\1)5(\1)6|5(\1)6(\1)7|6(\1)7(\1)8|7(\1)8(\1)9)' FROM DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6304a325c7283a7a9903e3e67f34f8e9)*